# Prove a sequence consists a subsequence of consecutive terms whose product is a perfect square

Tags: combinatorics, pigeonhole-principle

> Let $S$ be a sequence of $N$ numbers containing $n$ distinct positive integers. Prove that
> if $N>2^n-1$ then $S$ has a consecutive subsequence whose product is a perfect square. Use Pigeonhole principle.

I have been thinking that for a set that has $n$ distinct numbers will have $2^n$ number of subsets. And by the pigeonhole principle, there will be 2 sequence share the same combination. But I got stuck to find a perfect square.

Comment: Welcome  to Maths SX! May I observe that no pigeon is a prefect?

Comment: Yes of course. If there is another way to solve it. But I think that pigeonhole is suitable for this when I think about this question.

Comment: But what's a *prefect* square?

Comment: for example, 25 is a perfect square as it is the product of 5*5

Comment: Sure, but a prefect is not perfect, and vice versa.

Comment: I am sorry for the typo.

Comment: At least one of the distinct numbers repeats for $\geq \frac{2^n}{n}$ number of times. That tells something useful for this question.

Comment: Don't be sorry. It was a pleasant moment.

Comment: Hint: let $A_k$ be the set of numbers appearing an *odd* number of times in the first $k$ terms in the sequence.  If $A_k$ is the empty set for some $k$, then the product of the first $k$ terms is a perfect square.  What if $A_k \neq \emptyset$ for all $k$?

Answer (score 3):

Suppose your $n$ distinct numbers are $\{a_1,\cdots, a_n\}$ and that your sequence is $\{s_1,\cdots s_N\}$.  Of course each $s_i$ equals some $a_j$.

For each consecutive subsequence $T$ we define the $n$ tuples of parities, $\Delta (T)=(\delta_1, \cdots, \delta_n)$ where $\delta_i$ is $0$ if $a_i$ appears an even number of times in the subsequence and it is $1$ otherwise.    Note that there are $2^n$ possible values for $\Delta(T)$.

Consider first the $N$ consecutive subsequences $S_i=\{s_1,\cdots, s_i\}$.  Since there are at least $2^n$ of these we see that either every possible value for $\Delta (T)$ is hit or one value is hit twice.

If every value is hit then we have some $i$ for which $\Delta (S_i)=(0,\cdots, 0)$ and clearly that $S_i$ works.

If some value is hit twice then we have a pair $i<j$ such that $\Delta(S_i)=\Delta(S_j)$ and then the consecutive sequence $\{s_{i+1}, \cdots, s_j\}$ works.  And we are done.

Comment: What does Δ(Si)={0,⋯,0}  means?

Comment: It means that each of your $n$ integers appears an even number of times in the given sequence $S_i$.

Comment: Note I edited to replace the curly brackets with parentheses For each subsequence $T$, the $n-$tuple $\Delta(T)$ records the parity of the number of occurrences of each $a_i$ in $T$.  Thus if $n=4$ and your sequence was $T=\{a_2, a_1, a_1, a_2, a_4\}$ then $\Delta(T)=(0,0,0,1)$ since each of $a_1,a_2,a_3$ occurs an even number of times but $a_4$ occurs an odd number of times.